# Post data containing array of structs in swift

Tags: json, swift, post, struct

Here is the JSON I need to post:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "case_id": 1,
            "status_id": 5,
            "comment": "This test failed"           

        },
        {
            "case_id": 2,
            "status_id": 1,
            "comment": "This test passed",

        },

        ..

        {
            "case_id": 1,
            "assignedto_id": 5,
            "comment": "Assigned this test to Joe"
        }

        ..
    ]
}
```

What I've tried doing is this :

```
let parameters = [
                "results" : data
                ] as [String : Any]

            let postData =  try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
```

Here, data is an array of structs of the type (data:[param]) :

```
struct param {
        var status_id: Int
        var case_id: String
        var comment: String
    }
```

The code fails at JSONSerialization. It enters the catch() block. I tried giving the parameters like this and it worked,

```
let parameters = [ "results" : [
       [
            "case_id": "20275",
            "status_id": 5,
            "comment": "This test failed"           
        ],
        [
            "case_id": "20276",
            "status_id": 1,
            "comment": "This test passed",
        ],
                    ]] as [String : Any]
```

How can I reproduce this structure? Because I can't hard code the values of status id's and case id's. I store the status id's and case id's in arrays.I thought creating an array of structs and substituting the id values will be enough, unfortunately it's not working. How do I post the data then?

Comment: The param should be a dictionary do not make it with struct.

Comment: Request will be `[String:[[String,Any]]]`

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani, an array of dictionaries? Each dictionary containing the id's and the comment?

Comment: Yes absolutely.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani, thank you very much , it worked. But I had to use [String : [[String:AnyObject]]] instead.

Comment: No, worries You can use it. but I recommend to you if you use Swift 2.0> then use [String:Any]

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani, alright, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'param' should be a dictionary do not make it with struct.

The request body data type is: `[String:[[String,Any]]]`